# Rename files and extensions in one command in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix, command-line

Is there a way to rename multiple files in one command. In Windows, I am aware of the command

```
ren *.* *.jpg
```

Is there a similar command in Mac OS X that i could run, instead of hitting enter on each and every individual file and doing the renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With unix-like systems, it's easier to use find

```
find ./
```

(try this first to make sure that your list of files looks like what you were expecting

```
find ./ -exec mv ${} ${}.jpg \;
```

This will append .jpg to the end of every file found. The regex for changing the final extension, rather than just appending, is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

While using `find` and `for` loops are efficient, Perl usually comes with `/usr/bin/rename` (in Linux at least) but I'm not sure you have it on MacOSX (at least not in my old 10.3).

If you don't have it, you can get this script from [the CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.6/bin/rename.PL). And [this is how](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.6/bin/rename.PL) to use it:

```
$ ls
   tata.jpg  titi.jpg  toto.jpg  truc  tutu
$ rename -v 's/\.jpg$/.JPG/' *.jpg
   tata.jpg renamed as tata.JPG
   titi.jpg renamed as titi.JPG
   toto.jpg renamed as toto.JPG
$ ls
   tata.JPG  titi.JPG  toto.JPG  truc  tutu
```

Comment: rename is not installed on MacOS X 10.6.2 by default, either.  It is a script I copied from the original Camel book - it was dropped (for lack of space) in later editions.  I still use it for exactly such purposes.  The only oddball thing to worry about it is the Mac's case-insensitive file system.

Comment: For lack of space? `/usr/bin/prename` is hardly 3KB...

Comment: Rather strange is that the man page for rename is in OSX  but the function is not. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

This will work (and leads to much more flexibility):

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *.*; do mv ${file} ${file/%.*([^.])/.jpg}; done
```

There are also non-standard Unix command-line tools that can do the job more succinctly.

Comment: Isn't .* greedy? Without trying it, I'd guess it would move files.2009.12.28.pic to files.jpg, which could be very much the wrong goal

Comment: D'Oh!  you're right.  I'll fix.